# Same npm package working nicely on CodeSandbox but showing error on my local machine

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

Trying to integrate a rich text editor package on one of my reactjs projects named Dante3 which is nicely working on CodeSandbox but on my local machine showing error : "Uncaught TypeError prosemirrorState.PluginKey is not a constructor".
Error image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynhLK.png)

Note:The package Dante3 used ProseMirror(a rich text editor) on their building block.

I've maintained the same versions for all dependencies both on my machine and on CodeSandbox

Even I arise an issue on Dante3 GitHub repository and the owner himself also get confused about the issue and finally get back without any solution .

CodeSandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/dante3-react18-wejnp9

code on my machine :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqKfO.png)

and the dependencies : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3UGc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this issue as well. You may find [this thread](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/316) useful. Followed [this advice](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/316#issuecomment-507336690) specifically which was to remove node modules and install everything again as there seemed to be some dependency overlap. In my case the error arose because I was creating a custom extension with `Plugin` from `prosemirror-state` and was giving me a similar error to you but my stack trace included the `prosemirror-table` issue linked above.

Comment: I've already tried the process deleting the node_modules and package.lock.json and reinstalling the packages but still the same issue ... would you suggest me another solution ?